# Lvalue reference constructor is called instead of rvalue reference constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class F {
public:
   F() = default;
   F(F&&) {
      std::cout << "F(F&&)" << std::endl;
   }
   F(F&) {
      std::cout << "F(F&)" << std::endl;
   }
};

class G {
   F f_;
public:
   G(F&& f) : f_(f) {
      std::cout << "G()" << std::endl;
   }
};

int main(){
   G g = F();
   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
F(F&)
G()
```

Why `F(F&)` constructor is called instead of `F(F&&)` constructor in constructor of class `G`? The parameter for constructor of class `G` is `F&& f` which is rvalue reference but constructor for lvalue reference is called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why F(F&) constructor is called instead of F(F&&) constructor in constructor of class G?

Because `f` is an lvalue. Even though it is *bound* to an rvalue, and its type is rvalue reference to `F`, it is also a *named variable*. That makes it an lvalue. Don't forget that **the value category of an object is not determined by its type**, and vice versa.

When you pass an lvalue to a function, only lvalue references can be bound to it. You should change your code as follows if you want to catch rvalues only:

```
class G {
    F f_;
public:
    G(F&& f) : f_(std::move(f)) {
       std::cout << "G()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::forward<>()`, which is equivalent in this case, but makes your intent of *forwarding* `f` even clearer:

```
class G {
    F f_;
public:
    G(F&& f) : f_(std::forward<F>(f)) {
       std::cout << "G()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now this last definition is easy to extend so that both lvalues and rvalues of type `F` can be bound to the parameter `f`:

```
class G {
    F f_;
public:
    template<typename F>
    G(F&& f) : f_(std::forward<F>(f)) {
       std::cout << "G()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This allows, for instance, to construct an instance of `G` this way:

```
F f;
G g(f); // Would not be possible with a constructor accepting only rvalues
```

This last version has a *caveat* though: your constructor [**will basically work as a copy-constructor as well**](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205121901/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html), so you might want to explicitly define all the possible copy constructors to avoid awkward situations:

```
class G {
    F f_;
public:
    template<typename F>
    G(F&& f) : f_(std::forward<F>(f)) {
       std::cout << "G()" << std::endl;
    }
    G(G const&) = default;
    G(G&); // Must be defaulted out-of-class because of the reference to non-const
};

G::G(G&) = default;
```

Since non-template functions are preferred over instantiations of function templates, the copy constructor will be selected when constructing a `G` object from another `G` object. The same applies, of course, to the *move* constructor. This is left as an exercise.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I'm saying this : http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7f047abd729b8347039874dc9a5e8b7f-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94 . Read the comments.

Comment: @Nawaz: Oh, yes, I see your point now. You're right, I should have declared both the `const` and the non-`const` version of the explict copy constructor, otherwise the constructor template would be picked anyway. Edited, thank you.